# Getting User Creation Exception With the Jhipster Application

Tags: jhipster

I have successfully generated the application using Jhipster (Angular, MySQL). As an admin, I have logged in and trying to create a new user but I am getting the below error.

```
2021-05-10 21:55:14.218 ERROR 29756 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] com.kc.bsadhana.service.UserService      : Exception in createUser() with cause = 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused' and exception = 'Connection refused; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused'

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection refused; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:362)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:345)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.doIndex(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:143)
```

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:360)
    ... 198 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:849)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:259)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:246)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1613)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1583)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1553)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClient.java:970)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.lambda$doIndex$0(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:343)
    ... 197 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:589)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:839)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    ... 1 common frames omitted

2021-05-10 21:55:14.238 ERROR 29756 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] com.kc.bsadhana.web.rest.UserResource    : Exception in createUser() with cause = 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused' and exception = 'Connection refused; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused'

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection refused; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
```

In `application-dev.yml` file I have entered the database credentials :

```
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bsadhana?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: root
    password: rxxxx!
    hikari:
```

Even the jhipster related tables were created in my database. But when I am trying to create a new user it is throwing the above-reported error. is there anywhere else I need to enter these credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says your app cannot connect to your Elasticsearch instance, you should make sure you started it with following command as explained [in the doc](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-elasticsearch/):

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/elasticsearch.yml up
```